# Initializing a differentiable param in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to define a set of new parameters `B` in a pytorch model. I would like to initialize the new params with current weights of the model `W`.

**Question:** I want these params `B` to be differentiable, but autograd should not track their history to `W` (so `B` should have a new memory with no reference to `W`). What is the correct function to use?

I understand `B = W.clone()` will result in autograd tracking history of B to W while differentiating. Also I understand that `B = W.detach().clone()` will not be differentiable.

---

EDIT:

I believe `B = nn.Parameter(W.detach().clone())` should be the correct function. Is this correct and if yes, is this the simplest function to use?

Comment: What do you mean by "want params `B` to be differentiable"? Do you mean that gradients should be computed for them?

Comment: @akshayk07 Should be computable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it and one of them is

```
B = W.clone().detach()
```

Another elegant one comes to my mind is

```
B = torch.new_tensor(x, requires_grad=True)
```

which is much more readable and [the doc says](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.new_tensor.html?highlight=new_tensor) they are equivalent.

If you want it as a parameter to `nn.Module`, of course wrap it with

```
self.B = nn.Parameter(...)
```